# What intent-filters must my app cover to appear in chooser when requestion an image from an external app?

Tags: android, android-intent

What are the possible intent-filter I need to cover to make sure that any external app requesting an image will see my app in the list?

To clarify, I'd like my app to appear when doing the following:

[image] [image]

So far I've covered:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
</intent-filter>
```

However, if using the Tumblr app and pressing "Add photo", my app does not appear in the chooser dialog. Which filter am I missing out on?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had covered the correct intent-filters, however the Tumblr app requires the category OPENABLE, so instead of the filters I had I'm now using:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE" />
    <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
</intent-filter>
```

Only adding the line:

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE" />
```

Comment: do this automatically pick the image from my app or should i have to right some code? Can you help

Answer (score 1):

Some applications may specify the application to open, and some applications have already set the default applications to Open.

Answer (score 0):

The share feature uses the following intent filter

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
</intent-filter>
```

Remember that this does not mean an app is requesting a photo but that it wants to send one somewhere.

Comment: I might be missing out on something here, but simply adding this to my manifest next to the two others did not give me any luck (at least not for the Tumblr app).

Comment: @TragedyStruck go through [this](http://eggie5.com/8-hook-share-picture-via-menu-android) see if it helps.

Comment: It might be that my question is unclear. I'm not sharing a photo from my app. When I select "add photo" from the Tumblr app I want my app to appear as one of the choices, along with "Gallery". Is this still the correct filter for that?

Comment: @TragedyStruck nope! there seems to be some others that gallery might be using, here is a gallery [mainfest.xml](http://source-android.frandroid.com/packages/apps/Gallery/AndroidManifest.xml), try the ones under `com.android.camera.ImageGallery`

Answer (score 0):

Use this `<intent-filter>`:

```
<intent-filter
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="Share to my app">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
</intent-filter>
```