# How to make my app appearing in whatsapp gallery's ShareIntentProvider

Tags: android, whatsapp

I want to select image attachment through my application in Whatsapp.

In Whatsapp sending Attachment from Gallery page, the ShareIntentProvider would provide native Gallery app and Google's Photos to select image. How can I make my application support on it?

I know how to share image from my application to Whatsapp, but I don't know how to make Whatsapp allow my application to select image for attachment.

Comment: Some app would have set default application to handle an Intent. 
check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12208498/what-intent-filters-must-my-app-cover-to-appear-in-chooser-when-requestion-an-im

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `AndroidManifest.xml` for the `Activity` that you want to open (from whatsapp) add the following intent filters:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
    <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
    <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
</intent-filter>
```

Your applications should now display in the whatsapp gallery list,

Comment: but how user can choose image from my app?????? how to show user some gridview kindda stuff when he choose my app from the listing?

Comment: @Amulya Khare Its not working in Lollipop version, Its not prompting by OS to choose application, any idea for latest Whatsapp version?

Comment: Sorry bother you so many years later of this answer, but I'm having the same problem and nothing seems to work, if you can help me I'll be thankful, I post my question here (http://stackoverflow.com/q/43299778/5561657), is almost the same of this... please take a look on it. PLEASE. THX