# How I make my app to be shown on available apps that have audio to share

Tags: android, android-intent, whatsapp

I'm building a app with sounds to be shared via WhatsApp, it's almost done, however is missing a single thing, that I already tried everything, but nothing seems to work.
I wanna that when the user click on share button of own whatsApp (the one that is a clip) my app be listed on list of possible apps to do that action, this way:

[image]

I already tried
use a intent filter on a activity like

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
            </intent-filter>
```

and too

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
            </intent-filter>
```

however my app wasn't shown, I already saw that is possible with other apps, I'm just doing something wrong.
How I can do to make my app be listed? Anyone knows?
Really Thx.

**Note** - the image is just a example, not a real one 'cause I can't print the screen of a real device, then I found this one on internet :(

**EDIT 1**
I tried this way too, but did not work

```
<activity
        android:name=".activities.HomeActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
        </intent-filter>
```

//and too

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Replace With below code

//this is to get text from other app

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
        </intent-filter>
```

For more idea here is an official document form android : https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html

Comment: :( I tried this way but did not work... My app still wasn't shown... Any other idea? Thx

Comment: @Anita I tried with all, its not working in whatsapp. But it's working for other intent. like,

Intent intent_upload = new Intent();
        intent_upload.setType("media/*"); // "audio/*"
        intent_upload.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(intent_upload,1);

Comment: I also tried using media instead audio, but didn't work. But thx anyway. If you have any other idea let me know. :) I'll look for something on all internet, if I find out I'll post here to you know too. Really thx.