# How to get path data from image in gallery by using Content Resolver

Tags: android, imageview, android-contentresolver

I already successfully get the image from gallery but i cannot upload the image to server because the file is null. is there any code that i miss to add? i add imageView.getPath, but i only get the path from camera image to server, and get null image from gallery.

i got this path, content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A5755
but still cannot upload to server

```
private void getImageFromGallery(Intent data) {

    mSelectedImgURI = data.getData();

    mimeType = getImageExt(mSelectedImgURI);
    uploadDialog.dismiss();

    imgCategory.setImageURI(mSelectedImgURI);
}

private void getImageFromCamera(Intent data) {

    Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);

    String tempFileName = System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";
    File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),tempFileName);
    FileOutputStream fo;

    try {

        destination.createNewFile();
        fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
        fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
        fo.close();

        mSelectedImgURI = Uri.fromFile(destination);
        uploadDialog.dismiss();
        imgCategory.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Internal error - " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
}

public String getImageExt(Uri uri){
    ContentResolver contentResolver = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver();
    MimeTypeMap mimeTypeMap = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
    return mimeTypeMap.getExtensionFromMimeType(contentResolver.getType(uri));
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Picking an image file from Gallery using FileProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39097181/picking-an-image-file-from-gallery-using-fileprovider)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a method I normally use

```
 public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri uri) {
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
    return cursor.getString(idx);
}
```

This returns the file location and you can get the file by calling

```
File realFile = new File(getRealPathFromURI(mSelectedImgUri));
```

Comment: This answer should be with lots of likes, IT WORKS