# How to make app appear as an option application?

Tags: android, android-intent

What needs to be done to make your app appear as an option app.
For eg, when I select an image file, android shows me a list of applications to open the file with, like Gallery,Photos etc.
I want that android also shows my app in this list.

How to achieve this? I am unable to understand which android classes to use for it? Or do I need to modify manifest file to add some specific intents?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What intent-filters must my app cover to appear in chooser when requesting an image from an external app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12208498/what-intent-filters-must-my-app-cover-to-appear-in-chooser-when-requestion-an-im)

Comment: Thanks fro directing to that page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By defining intent filter you can achieve this. You can register your Android components via intent filters for certain events.If a component does not define one, it can only be called by explicit intents. The key for this registration is that your component registers for the correct action, mime-type and specifies the correct meta-data.

Eg.

```
<activity android:name=".BrowserActivitiy"
      android:label="@string/app_name">
<intent-filter>
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
 <data android:scheme="http"/>
</intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Above code will register an Activity for the Intent which is triggered when someone wants to open a webpage.

**Source:** http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidIntent/article.html